# Table of contents - Right side table

Tags: docsify

Is it possible to have a table of contents on the right side of the page ?

Similar to how it looks (preferably custom - skinnable) in the android docs: "On this page" ?

https://developer.android.com/games/develop/overview

If so how would it be implemented ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Docsify does not have any mecanism to generate a sub-toc in their out of the box solution. For further customisation, you need to develop plugins to do that. As the plateform is popular, there are fortunately a lot of plugins created by users on github.

I use this plugin [here](https://github.com/lyingdragon/docsify-plugin-page-toc) developped by Lyingdragon which works fairly well.

Add the following line to your index.html file :

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/docsify-page-toc/dist/docsify-page-toc.js"></script>
```

It creates the TOC on the side, with a depth of all the titles levels of your markdown file. You can customize the depth by configuring your index.html file. However, I don't use the configuration described byt the author of the plugin, because it does not work with my homepage.